# I want to use OpenCV library in my app with Android Studio(without manager)

Tags: java, android, opencv

I followed instructions found http://ashokvarma.me/android/how-to-setup-android-studio-with-opencv-opencv4android/  but I get error:

> "OpenCV/StaticHelper: First attempt to load libs fails"

I am using *opencv version 3.0.1*. This is my code:

```
static {
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug())
        Log.d("ERROR", "Unable to load OpenCV");
    else {

        Log.d("SUCCESS", "OpenCV loaded");
    }
}
```

The logcat result which I receive is:

> "Unable to load OpenCV"

Could anyone please help me out of this (I am struggling with this for days)?

Comment: where is your OpenCV native libs file located?

Comment: it is located in App/source/main/jniLibs